# Github Pages error

Tags: github-pages, nuxt.js

I wrote a web application on `nuxt.js`. I followed this instruction clearly.
[Nuxt.js deploy on GitHub Pages](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/github-pages)

But when I  deploy my app to Github Pages, there was an error on my site in the console

[image]

Here is my [site](https://sadybekovyernar.github.io/itunes-search/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.nojekyll` file is missing.

You have forgotten to commit the empty file called `.nojekyll` from `dist` to your GitHub project.

This is because GitHub Pages will by default ignore any files and folders prefixed by an underscore (like `_nuxt`), as documented here: https://github.com/blog/572-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages

Comment: Thanks for the answer! There was no `.nojekyll` in the folder `dist`. Despite this, I added an empty `.nojekyll` file to my github project. But the console errors did not disappear

Comment: be careful,  you have to put the `.nojekyll` file at root of your project (https://github.com/sadybekovyernar/sadybekovyernar.github.io) not in a subfolder (https://github.com/sadybekovyernar/sadybekovyernar.github.io/tree/master/itunes-search)